# Existence of the $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ for a differentiable $f$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I came across this question in a graduate analysis exam:

> Given a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(1) = 2$ and $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^4+f(x)^2}$, does the limit $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ exist?

I don't know exactly what areas of analysis am I supposed to look into for this problem. Since we know what $f(1)$ is, I tried to use MVT to see what happens when $x$ gets very big, i.e., $$f(x) - f(1) = f(x) - 2 = (x-1)f'(t) = \frac{x-1}{t^4+f(t)^2},$$
where $t \in (1,x)$ is the value from the statement of the MVT. So that $$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{t^4+f(t)^2} + 2.$$ Now since $f'$ is positive (at least for $x \geq 1$), we know that $f$ is strictly increasing, i.e., for $y<z$, we have $f(y) < f(z)$. So we can bound $f(x)$ as follows: $$\frac{x-1}{x^4+f(x)^2}+2 \leq f(x) \leq \frac{x-1}{5}+2.$$
As $x$ gets very large, it seems like the left side will tend to $0$, while the right side goes to infinity, so this bound is not very useful. Are there other ways to work this problem out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: since $f$ is strictly increasing and always positive, $f'(x) < 1/x^4$ for all $x$. What does that imply about $\int_1^x f'(t)dt$?

Comment: That the integral exists and is finite?

Comment: @KelvinLian Indeed. Now use FTC on the integral to get an upper bound for $f$.

Comment: So $$f(x) - 2 \leq \int^x_1\frac{1}{t^4}dt = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3x^3},$$ unless I computed my integral wrongly.

Comment: Then this implies that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \leq \frac{7}{3}$? And hence the limit exists?

Comment: @KelvinLian Yes. A strictly increasing function that is bounded above must necessarily have a limit.